# How to disable cache on chrome for Android?

Tags: google-chrome

How to disable cache on **chrome for Android**?

I change my page content, and refresh the page, but the content still is old.

I have set the nginx config like below, but it has no effect.

```
#disable cache
add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
add_header Pragma no-cache;
add_header Expires 0;
```

Is there a way to get my newest page without manually clear cache again and again?

Comment: Are you trying to do this for development? Or for real traffic?

Answer (score 23):

This may not be the easiest way, but it will 100% work and should be part of your development setup anyway.

Using Google Chromes web tools on Windows or Mac will allow you to do "[remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging)".

1. Enable remote debugging on Android device through Developer Menu in settings.
2. Connect phone to PC using USB
3. Open Google Chrome and access the developer console (F12)
4. Click on the three dots (top right) > more tools > Remote devices.
5. Scroll down to select your mobile device, at this stage you should see all chrome instances open on your phone. Select the instance you wish to "force reload and disable cache" by pressing `Inspect`
6. Another screen should appear allowing you to access the network tab and select "Disable Cache"

Comment: awesome men!!! Thanx for this tip. Unfortunately, you will have to keep the window opened at all times during the process, just like in for PC browsers. And the phone kind of becomes slower. But heck, it's better than nothing. Thanx

Comment: For those having issues getting their phone to connect to the debugging session, be sure to plug your phone in _after_ you press F12 and select "Remote Devices."  This will pop up the prompt to accept the debugging session on the phone which is needed to complete the connection.  You can read more about that [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/).

Comment: Samsung owners should also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354508/1202830) for some additional steps. Specifically, you may need to run `adb devices` to kick things off.

Comment: Even with "disable Cache" checked chrome sometimes use it!

Comment: In Google Chrome on Ubuntu I just don't see such an option in the "More Options" list.

Answer (score 10):

Currently there is no way to disable cache on chrome for Android but it is possible to clear the cache.

**UPDATE: As of now there is a way to disable cache with requires your phone to be connected and needs remote debugging, please refer to Dean Meehan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43457662/1330180) for more info**
Follow these steps to clear the cache.

http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/chrome-android/

1. Click on the menu button (three dots in the topright corner).
2. Click on **Settings** in the menu.
3. Click on **Privacy** in the menu.
4. Click on **Clear browsing data...** at the bottom.
5. Select **Empty the cache** from the list.
6. Confirm clear browsing data.

Comment: Please copy essentials from link you provided. After some period of time link may be broken, an answer won't be valid anymore.

Comment: I can't, I don't have that much reputation.

Comment: @Shariq: you are able to edit you own posts. Expand your answer with the relevant pieces from the link. You answer is getting pretty closed to getting deleted if you don't do so.

Comment: the point is to disable it so you don't have to go through these steps every single time

Comment: So, my best bet is to reload Chrome and open localhost in incognito tab... Because using pure Chrome when you have only Android device is pain for developer!

Answer (score 10):

I know the question is asking about disabling cache on chrome for Android, but this may help people looking for a solution to mobile development.

To see changes on your website with your Android device use the **New incognito tab** in chrome web menu.

1. Click top right drop down menu in chrome browser
2. Click **"New incognito tab"**
3. Navigate to your website and see all your most recent changes.

**IMPORTANT:** To see new changes after viewing with incognito, you must close the incognito mode completely and reopen due to the current tab also caching.

Comment: Helpful! I dunno why, but in latest version I have to reload whole Chrome to see changes.

Comment: The easiest way !

Answer (score 2):

To disable the cache first you'll have to disable scripts / css caching on the ones you are editing.

In order to do that, add a timestamp to your file inclusions :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/css/main.css?t={{ts}}'/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/static/scripts/main.js?t={{ts}}'></script>
```

`{{ts}}` being a timestamp (I'm using jinja templating).

Then if you edit your html page, you could change the request adding a random parameter to it as such :

test 1 :
mywebsite.com/this_page

test 2 :
mywebsite.com/this_page/?i=1

test 3 :
mywebsite.com/this_page/?i=2

...

It's more a hack than a real solution, but chrome kindly ignores the `cache-control` meta, so there aren't lots of clean way to do it.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, since I’m not using a PC for development.

Answer (score 0):

The following bash script will rename

`<script src="path/to/app.js"></script>`

to

`<script src="path/to/app.js?t=18:15:45></script>`

in an `index.html` file, which will prevent mobile caching.

```
#!/bin/bash

time=$(date +"%T")
sed -i "s/app.js/app.js?t=${time}/" ./path/to/index.html
```

Answer (score -1):

Download this app : App Cache Cleaner

1. Open the app
2. Go to the app settings via the '3 dotted' button

[screenshot](http://cdn2.ubergizmo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/ase.jpg)

3. Tick mark the option to show widgets and the rest is upto you

You may as well disable Chrome's Data Compression policy and preloading of pages.

As of now, there are no 'disable cache' option in chrome

[screenshot2](http://cdn2.ubergizmo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/ewq.jpg)

PS:i cud not show pictures because of my low rep, help me increase that too ;p

Comment: Please work on formatting, spelling, and grammar. It will help with achieving greater rep.