# Chrome DevTools Devices does not detect device when plugged in

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I cannot seem to get the DevTools Devices feature to work on my Samsung Galaxy S4 even after following the steps outlined at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/

My device has Chrome v32 and Chrome Beta v33, while my PC has Chrome v33 and Chrome Canary v35.

USB debugging is enabled on my device and device driver has been installed. I have never got the prompt as outline in step 3 from the above link to approve the RSA key fingerprint yet the device does connect to my PC to allow media transfer. I have even revoked all USB debugging authorizations as per the link above.

I don't have any thing extra installed on my PC for Android development which may perhaps be the issue. I wish to utilise this feature to inspect web pages from the devices point of view.

Comment: Hey everybody. DevTools technical writer here. Sorry to hear about all the troubles! The Remote Debugging doc will link to this post shortly. Please include your OS + Chrome Version (`chrome://version`) + Android Make & Model when describing what works for you.

Comment: @KayceBasques you mean this page links to here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: this question and its answers are all very out of date now. They just released an update, which is why I ended up here, that deprecates this menu and points to a new menu. Answer I needed was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231562/what-happened-to-the-remote-devices-panel/62608766#62608766

Comment: At one point this was working for me, and after not using this feature for awhile, it stopped working. I think there was a chrome update. After trying for awhile, it turned out it was just my USB cable. Make sure your cable supports data transferring. You should see a message pop up on you device saying the computer is trying to access your files. That's without having chrome open. It should just always happen when you plugin your device. Also, my device still doesn't appear in chrome, but port forwarding is still working for me.

Comment: i have restarted my chrome, its working fine now.

Answer (score 613, accepted):

To get the functionality up and running:

- Follow steps at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/
- Install Windows USB driver http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Android-USB-Driver-for-Windows
- Install Android SDK http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
- Install Android SDK Platform-tools http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html (this step was blocked on corporate wifi so I installed the single ADB package it required https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790)
- Use command prompt to run ADB, in cmd go to the install directory of the ADB tools and type:
- `adb.exe` (might need to start and stop ADB using `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`)
- Connect phone and browse to `about:inspect` in Chrome on desktop, ensuring a Chrome browser is open on your device

Following the above steps I got the RSA key fingerprint prompt to accept then I saw my device in Chrome.

Definitely not as easy as I thought it would have been but at least it now works.

**Update 24 February 2016**

So I updated to Windows 10 and now have a Samsung Galaxy S5, devices running Chrome v48.0.2564.116 m and v48.0.2564.95 respectively. Followed the steps from the Google docs and...it didn't work again, no RSA key prompt. So I began to follow my steps as above and thought there had to be a faster way as the Android SDK was over 1GB download.

This time I tried:

- Follow steps at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/
- Install Windows USB driver http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows (the PC alerted me saying it was already installed but I still did it anyway)
- Install the single ADB package required https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790)
- Go to the ADB install folder which for me was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot\`
- Open command prompt and run `adb devices` (alternatively I could have run `adb start-server` but the prior gives a more informational response)

Now, with Chrome open on my phone and `chrome://inspect/` open on my desktop I can see the inspect options.

Next problem: I need to repeat the same steps each time I reboot Windows. To solve that issue:

- Open a text editor and copy in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot\adb" devices`
- Save that file as `adb.bat` in the Windows Startup folder located at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`

*Note that the file does NOT need to be called adb.bat as long as it is a .bat file. The command you copied into the file has the default install path which you may need to alter for your set up.*

Now I have the Chrome Inspect feature working when I need it.

Bit thanks and shout out to all others who have contributed their answers to this question which helped guide me towards a useful update to my answer. Please give credit to other answers where you find they have helped you too.

Comment: I answered a similar question based on your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22037216/563970). Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I've been keeping an eye on this post when you initially asked. I had the same problem too. I had the driver installed and everything (I have Nexus 7) and it kept saying that I have the latest driver already installed. But turns out you have to be in Camera (PTP) mode to be able to update the driver with Google's driver. After that it was pretty much the same process as the documentation mentions. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: @Ash - can you chime in here with the details on the issue you had? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=361856#c2 We're trying to track down this problem. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing to note is if you are not getting an authorisation prompt, try disabling and re enabling usb debugging on your device - I followed all steps above and only got the prompt after doing that

Comment: Restarting the adb server fixed it for me.

Comment: Major thanks!  adb server-kill and adb server-restart worked for me.  I'm not sure if I needed the USB driver, but installed/reinstalled it anyway.  Don't forget to up-vote the question too!

Comment: Anyone ever hear of "target=_blank"??

Comment: Yep, installing Android SDK and then in your `%APPDATA%/Local/Android/sdk/platform-tools/` running the `adb.exe kill-` and `start-server` commands worked like a charm! Instant popup and RSA fingerprint check.

@TheHawk that's the old-school `rel="external"`. We usually support backwards compat. with, i.e. jQuery `$('a[rel="external"]').attr('target', '_blank');`.

Comment: Simply installing android sdk and sdk platform tools worked for me, soon as installation finished, got a remote debug request popup on galaxy s5

Comment: Without installing the SDK or the single ADB package, if you have done remote debugging with Firefox with the help of WebIDE you already have `adb.exe` in your Firefox profile folder `Data\profile\extensions\adbhelper@mozilla.org\win32`, open a cmd prompt there and use the `adb commands` above, works fine. Also I think it is a **disgrace** Google makes you sign in to Chrome **and** your Google account just to be able to remote debug a website or app, ugly data kraken! Did not have an account and did not want to give number, a friend sorted me, but come on, for debugging they also take data!

Comment: "ensuring a Chrome browser is open on your device" saved me

Comment: The Google Docs link (about the single ADB package required) in your answer is not working, I get: "We're sorry. You can't access this item because it is in violation of our Terms of Service."

Comment: I've tried the above steps, namely installing MinimalADB & running the daemon, and STILL cannot persuade my computer to recognise the existence of my Lenovo Tab 4 10.1 for debugging. The computer recognises it for file transfers in Windows Explorer, but NOT for anything else. And yes, developer options were enabled on the tablet when I tried this. Something that *works* would be welcome.

Comment: The SDK platform tools can be downloaded from Google here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html

Comment: @Marquizzo The funny thing is that the docs (as of the writing of this comment) actually link to this answer, I feel bad for anyone trying to solve this problem should this link ever break.

Comment: Here using windows 8, Samsung J2, using the method described on "Update 24 February 2016", worked perfectly!! There´s no need to Install Android SDK Platform-tools. Thanks.

Comment: Hello again, 3 years later. I thought this would have been fixed by now? I still need to do all these steps? That really sucks. Google/Samsung/Microsoft please team up or whatever and make our lives easier!

Comment: command "adb devices", response "daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037" FFS why there's no single mention of it in official troubleshooting

Comment: @PussInBoots FWIW, Google now links to this answer from their remote debugging tutorial.

Comment: I just ran your "Update 24 February 2016" steps with my Samsung Galaxy S10 and Windows 10 desktop and it worked on first try! Many thanks.

Comment: this link is broken.. 
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows
it seems that this is the updated one
https://developer.samsung.com/mobile/android-usb-driver.html

Comment: Thanks. Starting ADB server with the _"adb start-server"_ command works for me. I didn't need to do the other things, although I did install Android Studio, so other things probably have been installed in the process.

Comment: adb start-server fixed it for me.

Comment: this *really* needs an update for 2023, because `adb` hasn't been necessary for years now. You just plug in your device with a USB cable, after making sure developer options are enabled, and open `chrome://inspect` in Chrome on your computer. The rest happens all on its own (give or take an "allow X to Y" modal on your device).

Answer (score 151):

On a Galaxy S7 and Windows 10 laptop, all I had to do whilst connected to the computer was change the USB connection mode to **"Audio Source"** (Phone Settings > Developer Options > USB Configuration).

This then immediately came up with the on-device prompt to allow the RSA key fingerprint. Then the dev tools on computer recognised my device.

Why this works I do not know, however it is by far the simplest of solutions, and without the need for installing unnecessary software.

<strike>I have also had some luck changing it to **"MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)"** mode too, but only on occasion.</strike>

Edit:

The MTP option no longer works for me.

In addition to **Audio Source**, setting the connection mode to **MIDI** also works. It is a lot easier to change the connection mode by accessing it straight from the device's notification bar - Tap the "Transferring media files via USB" or the equivalent notification.

Using **MIDI** is probably the easiest of the two since it doesn't require going into several setting screens to access it.

Comment: i think this is best answer i give it plus and i think u guys also must do it so ppl don't use other methods

Comment: Changing **Select USB Configuration** to **MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)** also worked for me on a Nexus 5X.

Comment: I should have mentioned... (Ironically, I forgot what worked and found myself scouring this answer 2 months later...) Once *again*... this worked for me on a Galaxy S8 and Windows 10.

Comment: After trying and fighting with Chrome's "getting started" guide and the Samsung USB drivers, changing from MTP to MIDI worked straight away! - Galaxy S6 Edge

Comment: Working for Honor 10 (COL-L29).

Comment: One point to add: the sequence of events. 1) unplug USB cable; 2) change USB Configuration to Audio Source (it will still say MTP). 3) plug USB cable in. This for a Note 9.

Comment: Works for me on Samsung S6 Edge with Android 7.0. Thanks a million!

Comment: (2019) For Pocophone F1, using File Transfer protocol works.

Comment: I hate "this works" without knowing why! Can someone please investigate why it is working using this method?

Comment: For reference: Samsung S8 / USB-configuration / "MIDI". After enabling "MIDI" and unplugging and plugging the USB cable back in Windows 10 started installing some drivers. I wonder exactly which drivers it installs!? Anyone know?

Comment: Changed to change the USB connection mode to "Audio Source" on Galaxy S6. It works. @Studocwho, You are King!

Comment: I have an older Samsung mobile device that doesn't have **USB Configuration** option under **Settings -> Developer Options** so I can't choose **MIDI** or **Audio Source**. The only available options on these older devices are **MTP** and **PTP** (and neither of them allow devtools to recognize your android device). So I executed `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` as others have suggested. This is the only thing that worked for these older devices without **USB Configuration** option.

Comment: The only solution that works. Google, shut down your guide pages and go home.

Comment: Worked for me, i have done many other steps but nothing. That was the thing and worked for me. Galaxy s7

Comment: With samsung s10 I just got it to work by setting Developer > Default USB configuration to "Transferring files / Android auto"

Answer (score 84):

*(Note - this worked for me using a Samsung S6. I'd appreciate any comments on the phone version used, for anyone these instruction work for)*

If your phone is connecting to your computer and being recognised on the computer, and you've enabled USB debugging on your phone, but the phone doesn't appear under 'Remote devices' in the Chrome developer tools, then you can first try restarting the automatic discovery process by selecting the following on your phone - 'Settings > Developer Options > Revoke USB Debugging Authorizations'.

If this doesn't work, then the problem is likely that the Android Debug Bridge Daemon is either missing or not running on your computer (info about ADB -
 https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html)

You don't need the full Android SDK to use ADB, you can download the standalone Android SDK Platform Tools from here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html

First, install the tools for your platform. I'm using Windows, and the steps for me were:

-Unzip the download into c:\platform-tools (I just put it here for
   convenience, you can choose a different location).

-Open command prompt (run as administrator) in folder, and run the
   following command:

```
adb devices
```

(The adb.exe is in our folder).  This will start the daemon and show you a list of attached Android devices.

If you see 'unauthorized' next to a device, it means you have to unlock your phone and choose 'allow access to device data', then 'always allow access from this computer'. You should then see your phone connected in the developer console:

[image]

You'll need to have the Daemon running every time your computer restarts. Put a .bat file in your startup folder, to run the daemon every time your computer starts (if you've been following my instructions exactly, the content of the .bat file you'll need to create will be `c:\platform-tools\adb devices`).

> If you now have difficult accessing a URL (e.g. 'localhost') that
>   you're sending to Chrome on your Android device  (via the Chrome dev
>   tools on your computer), that's a different issue. See this question
>   for advice
>   [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)
>
> (in brief, you need to make sure your computer and phone are connected
>   on the same network, so connect both onto the same wi-fi network or
>   tether your computer to your phone's hotspot, then run ipconfig to get
>   your wireless IPv4 IP address, and use that IP in the URL you want to
>   view on your phone)

---

**Note:** For the initial debugging connectivity to work, you need to be using MTP mode (Media Transfer Protocol) on your Android, for USB transfer (MTP is the default). There's a fix mentioned in one of the answers that involves switching this mode to something else, however that probably just triggers some type of re-recognition, and you're likely to be automatically switched back to MTP mode anyway if you disconnect then reconnect the phone.

Comment: TY! This worked for me. Even though I had an ADB driver installed the deamon wasn't running. Run the above and it started, device shows now.

Comment: Thank you! For Samsung phone users, follow these steps!

Comment: Just another thank you! This was the answer for my Note 8. Funny thing is I already had `adb` installed, I just hadn't done an `adb devices` with my new phone.

Comment: most simplistic answer

Comment: Works on Samsung Galaxy S10e. Thank you. I was trying to debug a javascript SPA app with Vue.js and was not aware I had to install Android SDK.

Comment: This solution seemed to be an overkill but after literally nothing else worked, this one saved me. I guess that's what you get for judging by appearance.

Comment: @Qwerty - yes unfortunately this kind of issue is always awkward, and the only good way to deal with it is to ensure you completely understand the issue and how the stuff works - that's what my answer tries to help you with. Glad it helped, that's the point :)

Comment: In my case, using MacOs, I had to type by termial : ./adb devices !

Comment: Running `adb devices` in Terminal (Mac) worked for me. It reported that the daemon wasn't running so it started it up. Once that happened my Samsung device was recognized - I also had revoked USB Debugging Authorizations on the device.

Comment: This is the simplest answer. Works on my Galaxy S8+

Answer (score 82):

If you are using **"MTP mode"** for USB computer connection.
Change it to "PTP mode" or "Card reader mode".

I have same issue and it works fine to me.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to unplug and replug in the usb cable after changing the setting.

Comment: This is wrong.  The screen that gives you the option between MTP mode and PTP mode usually means that you don't have USB debugging enabled.

Comment: Worked for me as well, Mac OS X 10.11.4 with LG G3 Android 5.0

Comment: Found it under Developer options > Select USB configuration. Changed it to "PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol)", but didn't solve the problem

Comment: I just changed the USB cable and it worked! (the phone was charging with the non-working cable though)

Comment: This made my computer to add the driver, that was fine. but still not recognized

Comment: @zok you may have charging only USB cable. Such cable needs only 2 wires whereas normal USB cable contains 4 connected wires.

Comment: I have a Galaxy S7 and Windows 10, and I had to change my USB connection to "Audio Source" mode, whilst connected to the computer. This immediately came up with the on-device prompt to allow the RSA key fingerprint. Then the dev tools on computer recognised my device.

Comment: @Studocwho answer worked for me on Win 10 Galaxy S7 Edge - massively simpler than all the other suggestions. Wonder whether you should add it as a proper answer as others could easily miss this in the comments

Comment: @theotherdy As per your suggestion, I've added my comment as an answer for future reference.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/49193147/2358222

Comment: Change to MTP mode solved the problem on HTC 10 / Android 8.0.0.

Comment: I had to switch to "MIDI mode" for my Samsung Galaxy A5 (SM-A510F) to make it work.

Comment: changing MTP Mode to PTP Mode solved the problem on my Device

Comment: i don't think this solution will work for everybody. It didn't work for me. What really worked for me was to use `adb.exe` from Android SDK platform tools to restart the adb server using the command `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`. If changing 'MTP' to 'PTP' works for you, then i would guess that changing to 'PTP' restarts adb server.

Comment: On a Google Pixel 3XL apparently the default USB mode is "No datatransfer" (translated from Danish). I changed it to PTP and remote debugging worked immediately.

Comment: Helped on Sony Xperia! To setup PTP I should enable developer mode, and enter developer settings

Answer (score 49):

Samsung Note 8 User here - all i had to do was

1. Enable USB Debugging on the phone.
2. Install and run the "ADB and Fastboot" tool
3. Input command `adb devices` in the adb prompt.
4. Go to `chrome://inspect/#devices` and the device shows up.

After that i got a message on my phone and chrome recognized the phone.

Comment: Did the trick on my Samsung Galaxy S8 after running adb inside of the windows command prompt and authorizing on my device.

Comment: Worked on Samsung Note 9

Comment: Worked on Samsung Galaxy A10.

Comment: Worked on Samsung S8

Comment: Worked on Samsung S10+

Comment: I had to first run ADB, (I've opened android studio) then disconnect and reconnect my smartphone to make it work. The devices was showing up here `chrome://inspect/#devices` but not with `adb devices`

Answer (score 46):

**workaround if you don't have ADT (Android Development Toolkit) installed:**

Managed to detect android based Samsung Galaxy phone after downloading [andorid SDK platform-tools.zip](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=9390355257214632011) and running the following command: "adb devices".
It started some deamon, found attached device, and I was also able to see it in chrome canary inspect tab.

previously I also installed ["Universal ADB driver"](https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver) but not sure if this was required

Comment: After so much time this is the one that work for me!, I think it has something to do with daemon not running. when you run the command "adb devices" starts that service.

Comment: I found that switching the usb connection on the pc also helped the issue.

Comment: For anyone that arrives here, you don't need the SDK platform, you *only* need the Universal ADB Driver.

Comment: **PERFECT**  Thank you!

Comment: This answer along with @Adorjan Princz's answer below solved my freaking problem. Brand new galaxy S8+ btw

Comment: Installing the Universal ADB driver fixed the problem for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I installed the "Android SDK Platform-Tools package" and ran "adb devices" and it worked right away. No need for universal driver. I will mention that I from previous attempts had installed samsungs windows driver (unclear if needed)

Comment: "adb devices" starts that service - works for me after I spent some time for restarting/rebooting and other useless acttions

Comment: Following @adamdport comment , here is official download link for ADB as standalone https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools

Answer (score 38):

I know this is an old question but here is my answer that solved it for me.  I had gone through all of the articles I could find and tried everything.  It would not work for me on a mac or PC.

Solution:  Use another USB cable.

I must have grabbed a poor quality cable that did not support file transfers.  I used a different USB cable and immediately got prompted for ptp mode and authorization for remote debugging.

Comment: that worked for me. I was using an USB cable that was charging the phone  even though Chrome couldn't recognise the device

Comment: This is one of the most brilliant answers I've ever seen here. So simple, so obvious! Thanks

Comment: I seriously wish I had more upvotes for this answer.

Comment: USB charging cables have only 2 wires whereas real USB cables have 4 wires. The 2 extra wires are used for data transfers.

Comment: I cannot state how important it is to try this. If possible always use the cable that came with the device. If it's not a real USB cable it doesn't matter what steps above you follow, it won't work.

Comment: i dont believe this is the only answer works. huawei that looks like ipx

Comment: It was the cable here too. How could one test if a cable is good or not?

Comment: Interesting. This works for Samsung S8 and above? Anyone tried any of those devices?

Comment: @henon with a cable that supports data transfer, you can access the phones files. just like a usb-stick.

Comment: Thanks. I was connecting a Macbook Pro to a Galaxy Note. I had been trying a small usb-2 to usb-c connector but that was the issue. When I used a usb-c to usb-c (comes with the MBP power adapter), then it worked. And I installed adb.

Comment: The year is 2022 but this is still relevant. Worked for me also! Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

**Samsung phone + PC with Windows**

First of all you need to turn on USB debugging on your phone:

1. Settings / About phone / Software information / Build number 
   *(tap it 7 times to turn on developer mode)*
2. Settings / Developer options / USB debugging *(turn it on)*

Then on your PC:

1. Install Samsung USB driver
   https://developer.samsung.com/mobile/android-usb-driver.html
2. Install ADB https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790 *(in the forum scroll down to the section "Downloads" to get the newest version of ADB)*
3. After ADB installation CMD should pop up -> start ADB with command "adb devices"
   *(for example "C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot> adb devices")*
4. Connect your phone to your PC with USB cable
5. Alert about the connection should pop up on your phone *(allow it)*
6. In Chrome on your PC open Developer tools / More tools / Remote devices and
   you should finally see your phone being detected

Comment: Worked for Galaxy Fold as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks to the info presented in the comment above, I was able to get this working for my Samsung 9. Thank you! : )

Comment: I was only missing the installation of ADB. After that it worked like a charm :) Thanks for this.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 31):

I have been using this tool for years on different computers and with different devices. I often found that chrome / ADT does not see my device.

In this case only thing that works for me is to **reset ADB deamon**:

```
adb kill-server
```

or / and

```
adb usb
```

After you re-plug your device a message will be shown on your device asking you to allow USB debugging from the computer connected. It's really important that this request be allowed.

Comment: the adb usb return me "error: device '(null)' not found" any idea?

Comment: @BraianMellor Got the same error, but I started to see my device after that

Comment: Great! This works for my Samsung Galaxy S8. Thanks.

Comment: `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` is the only thing that worked on my old Samsung Galaxy Tab 3. Other solutions suggest changing 'USB configuration' to 'Audio source' or 'MIDI', but that isn't necessary. In fact, I have 'USB configuration' set to 'Charging' on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S, but I'm still able to connect the android device to devtools. I'm guessing that setting 'USB configuration' to 'Audio source' or 'MIDI' resets the ADB daemon by executing `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` under the hood

Answer (score 13):

ADB must be running. Just go to

`C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` and run `adb devices`, daemon should start and then show all connected devices.

Comment: Thank god, this has been an issue for so long with my samsung galaxy s8 and windows 10.

Answer (score 11):

**Ubuntu Linux 20 update**:

You may no longer have to do any of the commands below. `sudo apt install -y adb` is sufficient. Chromium 83 has that port forwarding rule enabled by default

**Older answer**:

For anyone using Ubuntu, I used the following:

https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules

Take note of the add group name command needed for Ubuntu 16 users.

I also installed the ADB tools `sudo apt install android-tools-adb` and `sudo apt install android-tools-fastboot` and didnt need the whole Android SDK

Lastly, don't forget to add the port forwarding in the devtools settings next to device where your phone has finally connected, i.e. 8080 | localhost:8080

Comment: ```sudo apt install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot``` was enough in my case. Thanks!

Comment: What did the trick for me after never having to worry about connectivity issues, was to click on the "eject" icon that appears in the top bar when you plugin the usb, then click on my phone (Nokia 6) in the dropdown menu that gets displayed, then the phone prompted for the rsa key check and it was suddenly working.

Comment: Ubuntu Linux 20 update: no longer had to do any of these. `sudo apt install -y adb` was sufficient. Chromium 83 has that port forwarding rule enabled by default.

Comment: used the github project above but had to replace the 51-android-rules with a rule specific to my phone and the adbusers group it had me create. i did have to install adb to get it to work. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771918/how-do-i-set-up-udev-rules-for-debugging-a-physical-android-device-with-android

Answer (score 10):

Had a nightmare with this today **Samsung Galaxy Note 9** and a **Windows 10** Laptop **without Android Studio**. Here are working steps to get debugging.

1) Enable developer mode on the phone in the usual manner and turn on "USB Debugging".

2) On your computer install the Samsung USB Drivers for Windows https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows

3) Open Chrome on your Computer - bring up Remote Devices in dev console (at the moment it will say no devices detected).

4) Connect your phone to your computer via USB cable.

5) Accept any prompts for authorisation and wait until the computer says "your device is ready.." etc.

6) On your phone, swipe down the top menu and tap "P Android system" - select "MIDI" under "Use USB for".

7) Various setup notifications will appear on your PC, when they are finished you will get the authorisation prompt for debugging on your phone. Accept it! Wait a few more second and you will find the phone now appears in Chrome Dev tools on the computer, and will be connected in a few more seconds.

You're welcome.

Comment: Besides the fact that I need to seelct the MIDI option everytime I connect the device, it worked like a damn charm. This is the first solution that really worked without any attempt/fail loop.

Comment: You can enable dev mode by going to Settings -> About and then tapping the build number 7 times. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866412

Answer (score 8):

run `adb` command line. like this

```
adb devices
```

Comment: Brilliant. Requires Android Studio or ADB installed though

Answer (score 7):

If you're on windows, you need to install the drivers for your phone.  You can get them [here](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows).

If it still doesn't work, I've had luck connecting by manually restarting the Android Debug Bridge manually. More info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9966660/1876861).

Comment: Already had the drivers installed, but after reading the steps in the other article you linked to I installed a few more things on my PC to get it working. Added those steps as a reply to my own question.

Comment: Thanks, i needed these drivers ;)

Answer (score 7):

What I had to do was **disable "Discover network targets" at chrome://inspect/#devices**.

That's the only thing that solved it for good in my setup(chrome Version 78.0.3904.97 deepinOS/debian based).

Answer (score 5):

Chrome "Remote device" stop working after a few months when I didn't use it.

**I resolved this issue :**
in "development option" of my device (samsung J3) I canceled usb debugging authorization
then in my computer, I execute "adb devices" in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools" folder
a prompt appears in my device asking me weather I allow my computer to debug apps or not.
I click yes then chrome has detected my device

Comment: yeah, the `adb.exe` command under Android sdk platform tools was the key to solving this issue of not having Chrome recognize my android device.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome appears to have bug renegotiating the device authentication. You can try disabling USB Debugging and enabling it again. Sometimes you'll get a pop-up asking you to trust your computer key again.

Or you can go to your Android SDK and run `adb devices` which will force a renegotiation.

After either (or both), Chrome should start working.

Answer (score 3):

If running on **Huawei** or **Honor** phones, make sure to install and run **HiSuite** on your computer. USB debugging only works when HiSuite is on.

Comment: You will have to open HiSuite for the phone's connection prompt to show up but you don't need to connect HiSuite with the phone. Another important thing is to choose PTP (picture transfer) instead of charge or MTP

Answer (score 2):

I tried @maurice cruz answer and was unable to get the actual drivers. Then I found [this post](http://www.technobuzz.net/install-lg-g3-lg-drivers-windows-mac-usb-adb/) which had a download for global LG driver (not sure if it covers all, but many) for their devices. After installing, then toggling usb debugging off then back on, I was prompted with RSA acceptance.

Answer (score 2):

None of the mentioned answers worked for me. However, what worked for me is port forwarding. Steps detailed here:

1. Ensure you have adb installed (steps [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/) for windowd, mac, ubuntu)
2. Ensure you have chrome running on your mobile device
3. On your PC, run the following from command line:

   `adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote`
4. On running the above command, accept the authorization on your mobile phone. Below is the kind of output I see on my laptop:

   `$:/> adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote`

   `* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *`

   `* daemon started successfully *`
5. Now open your chrome and enter 'localhost:9222' and you shall see the active tab to inspect.

[Here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging-legacy) is the source for this approach

Answer (score 1):

I am new to app programming and this was the first problem I ran into when I tried to get a sample program debug using my LG G3 device. The post above with detailed instructions should work for all. I am adding my experience in case it helps other:

I had followed instructions step by step but one. That is, installing the USB driver from my OEM. My phone kept notifying that the debugging is on (in the notification area) and I could transfer data as well as charge. That made me think that appropriate USB drivers are installed. But it wasn't. Finally I went to [LG site](http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware) and downloaded the USB driver for my LG G3. Right after I installed the driver and reconnected the phone to the computer via the cable, I got the RSA key prompt. My Chrome now detects it and I was able to get my app run on my phone via Android studio as well.

Comment: I've got an LG G2 mini and had to install LGMobileDriver_WHQL_Ver_4.0.4 in order to catch it with adb. The driver was downloaded for some other G2 model because I didn't find g2 mini on the official site.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with six different Android devices and multiple cables and I have to say that debugger works unstably. Sometimes it can see the device, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes restarting Chrome helps. Here is a related bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=788161, may be you can contribute with your evidence.

Answer (score 1):

Toggling 'Discover USB devices' seemed to kickstart something after I'd toggled the enable debugging feature on and off on the phone.

Also a different cable may have been the issue. My case may have been interfering with the connection for data, but not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using a Samsung Galaxy S9 running Android Pie. -- May 2019
Similar to the answer above, and NickW's post for that answer:
Once your device is connected, instead of going to settings, go to the phone's notification bar > Android System and 'Tap for other USB options.' Select MIDI under the options and you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem **without** installing any Samsung or Android SDK drivers or having to select MIDI or Image transfer options, as detailed in the many answers above spanning several years.

For me, on Windows 10, the problem was caused by the Windows 10 built-in app called `Your Phone`.  I only had to `repair` the app in its `Advanced Settings`.  There might be an easier way to access the app's settings but I accessed them this way:

1. System Settings
2. Add or Remove Programs
3. Click `Your Phone` from the
   list
4. Select `Advanced Options`
5. Select `Repair` under `Reset` options

After this, when I reconnected and toggled `USB Debugging` on my Android phone (Samsung A30), my phone prompted me for approval of the RSA key fingerprint, which allowed Chrome DevTools to finally recognize my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this here for reference, I was trying to connect an LG G5 Android phone and Chrome dev tools did not recognize it until I downloaded the LG usb driver [here](https://www.mylgphones.com/lg-android-usb-device-drivers).

Good luck, all!

Answer (score 0):

There is a necessary step which is not detailed:

ADB must be running (it is not because it is installed that it will run to establish the connection)

For an unknown reason to open "developer tools" on chrome (canary) will not necessarily launch the run of ADB with good parameters. Then you will not see on the smartphone the question "Confirm remote connection with 'your pc address' " while on PC you can see on the connection panel "pending unknown connection". Then necessarily if this not happens the connection will not be established. Note that some other tools launches ADB but what important is to launch ADB and establish the connection.

**When you run ">ADB connect 'IPofYourSmartphone port' " or ADB is run by a soft to get right connection, ADB sends the request which show the panel confirmation on your Smartphone**

**This is too valid for USB or Wifi connection.**
If you use on android a tool like "ADB wireless by Henry" you will get a full guide to get a wifi debugging remote connection.

Answer (score 0):

Using an LG G7 and Windows 10 at the moment. For me, once the phone is physically connected, changed the USB connection mode to *Photo transfer* (I was originally using *File transfer*) and Chrome's Remote Devices detected my phone. As far as I know, I have only the mobile driver installed, no ADT etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have android 9 in your mobile device you must update Android SDK in Android Studio.

- Open Android studio and go to Settings.
- System Settings\Android
- Select Android SDK (You will see new version of SDK)
- Click to apply
- Your mobile phone will want to access now on MIDI mode.

Answer (score -1):

On the phone make sure that the debugging mode is turned on.

Answer (score -1):

This Worked for me:

Go to *Developer Options* on your device and disable the "**USB Debugging**" and after sometime enable it again.