# How do I extract and view cookies from Android Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome

Is there any way for me to get and read cookies from my Android Chrome browser?

Thank you.

Comment: I sure hope not, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: well, you can get, read, and edit cookies from Chrome Desktop (windows).    The Google Sync feature does not work in syncing the cookies...

Answer (score 55):

You can view cookies in Chrome on Android if you connect your Android device to a PC/Mac/laptop via USB. No rooting required. The laptop needs to have Chrome installed. You can then inspect the content on your Android device in Chrome on your laptop by visiting `chrome://inspect/#devices`

There's a little more to it than that, you need to enable developer mode on your Android device:

Settings -> About Phone -> Build number. Tap build number 7 times.

Then under Settings you will see a new item - "Developer Options".

Within Developer Options enable USB debugging.

If you don't see your connected device listed on your laptop Chrome URL: `chrome://inspect/#devices` then you might need to install a USB driver. Or disconnect and reconnect device after installing USB driver.

Details here - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Once you can inspect content you can get cookies from the network tab in the same way as you would in Chrome on your laptop.

> Note : This doesn't work in inCognitoMode

Comment: I like the idea but it does not work... reason unknown.

Comment: Now it works after following the idea and this question, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925992/chrome-devtools-devices-does-not-detect-device-when-plugged-in. It seems like `adb` is required to get RSA footprint. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. Nice...

Answer (score 20):

Follow these steps

1: Go the web page that you want the cookies from.

2: In the URL type the following:

`javascript:alert(document.cookie);`

Then press ENTER

Just type, DO not PASTE!

Comment: it's a fast way to show the cookie, thx

Comment: This is a interesting way to do this, but its only show a small part of all cookies.

Comment: I wish there must be another way!

Comment: `javascript:document.cookie;` works better 

Comment: It's also possible to put them in a prompt() window to make them copy-pastable:
`javascript:prompt("Cookies", document.cookie);`

Comment: Thanks @DimosthenisNikoudis works well. But is there any other way than just typing it in every time?

Comment: Would love to know as well. Chrome defaults to Google search for anything pasted, with seemingly no way of changing it.

Comment: To anyone who is still here, my answer shows you do not have to type it all. It also makes it easier for exporting.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the the net-export page chrome://net-export/ . I guess that should work, or at least you can use it to make a .json file, viewing it's contents however, I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

As Luis wrote, you can use `javascript:alert(document.cookie);`, however, you can copy and paste the second part. Also, prompt is better because it makes the cookies easier to export. TL;DR: copy this: `prompt("Cookies", document.cookie);`. After that, TYPE `javascript:` in the address bar of the site you want to download from, paste what you just copied, and enter.

Answer (score 0):

Without an external PC and a cable, but on a rooted device, it is possible to access the cookies database by a tool like [SQLight Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tomminosoftware.sqliteeditor) by opening this file:

> /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies