# How to get cookie (full) from a site in Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, cookies

I tried solutions from [How do I extract and view cookies from Android Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101403/how-do-i-extract-and-view-cookies-from-android-chrome#comment125364082_68317037)

It works great and the code is below (runs javascript)

```
javascript:document.cookie;
```

By @user123 - https://stackexchange.com/users/7946910/user123

And 2nd one also works the same by https://stackexchange.com/users/2318765/dimosthenis-nikoudis

```
javascript:prompt("Cookies", document.cookie);
```

But both codes get only partial cookies value  and the site from which I want to get cookies ( https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain ) has 2 types of cookies, "set-cookie" and "cookie".

And I want to get full "cookie" value ( from nsit=xf0xV....TO....NO=~1 ) as shown in the below pic in Android (in chrome, but any browser you suggest will also be fine)

[Number 3, cookies I'm looking to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dLea.jpg)

**Summary of how to get cookies value in Android chrome**

1. Open site [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)
2. Type above code in url & you will get cookie value

Answer (score 2):

Use chrome://net-export/
Only it works fine.

- Capture Raw Data and upload the file in https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/#import this site to see all data.

I am describing the steps:

1. After Importing the file, select EVENTS Tab.
2. type: "type:SESSION WebsiteName.com", then some entries wil appear.
3. Click on the entry to see the details.
4. press ctrl+F and write cookie: you will get all the cookies.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

answers.

{"error_code":401,"error_msg":"Invalid username or password (401)","error_data":"{"error_title":"Wrong Credentials","error_message":"Invalid username or password"}","request_args":[{"key":"api_key","value":"882a8490361da98702bf97a021ddc14d"},{"key":"email","value":"yanto.terlalu.1\u0040gmail.com"},{"key":"format","value":"JSON"},{"key":"generate_session_cookies","value":"1"},{"key":"locale","value":"en_US"},{"key":"method","value":"auth.login"},{"key":"password","value":"--sanitized--"},{"key":"return_ssl_resources","value":"1"},{"key":"v","value":"1.0"},{"key":"sig","value":"52845d5c5a86555b7e47c1962edf8a40"}]}

Comment: Please format the code in your answer and add some details.