# How do I set up udev rules for debugging a physical android device with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services

In the past I've never had to set this up, but I updated Android Studio to version 2.3.1 today and got this error when clicking debug:

```
05/03 17:19:19: Launching app
$ adb push app-debug.apk {path on my computer}
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: insufficient permissions for device: verify udev rules.
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information.
Error while Installing APK
```

I went to the page they specified, where they told me to make the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

So I did, adding this line:

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`

For my (Huawei) Nexus 6P.

I also added the `debug` section to `build.grade`, as they specified.

However, I still get the same error. I tried substituting my own linux user group in place of `plugdev`, but that didn't fix the issue either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> be aware that it might report different IDs, depending on the current USB mode of the device.

therefore it's important is to enable USB debugging **first** ...

and **then** use `lsusb` in order to obtain the vendor & product IDs ...

```
Bus 001 Device 070: ID 18d1:4ee7 Google Inc.
```

the culprit might be the vendor ID, where `12d1` is Huawei - and `18d1` is Google.

... whatever `lsusb` outputs goes to `udev` rules:

```
# angler (Nexus 6P)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee7", MODE="0600", OWNER="yourusername"
```

then run:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not add the proper `ATTR{idVendor}` attribute. To do that, do the following:

```
$ sudo adb devices
List of devices attached
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
XXXXyyyy    device
```

1. After running `adb devices` you'll see the output above.
2. Copy the first 4 bytes of the `device` output (so, `XXXX`). Replace those with `ATTR{idVendor}=="XXXX"` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` and restart `udev`.

As the comment below indicated, the above method may not work; another option is to use `lsusb` or tail `dmesg`.

Comment: This doesn't always work. The `XXXXyyyy` in `adb` might not be the device ID. Use `dmesg` to find out the device ID and add that to your rules.