# Can't inspect android app on chrome remote debug

Tags: android, google-chrome, remote-debugging, android-debug

I was trying to use Stetho to debug my application and followed the steps here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging to enable chrome remote debug, but I can't inspect my app. The device is recognized, but no inspect link:
[image]

What I have done:

- Enabled USB debug on my device
- Have checked that my android version is above 4.4 (is Android 7)
- Have tried to install the `ADB` and run `adb devices`

What could I be missing?

**EDIT:**

I did some more tests with the following results:

- Tested on an emulator and I still can't inspect my APP
- I can inspect chrome tabs

So the problem seems to be something I did or didn't in my APP.

Comment: what happens when you run adb devices?

Comment: I lists the devices: in one line: `List of devices attached` and in the other line `f0aaa85d        device`

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925992/chrome-devtools-devices-does-not-detect-device-when-plugged-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925992/chrome-devtools-devices-does-not-detect-device-when-plugged-in)

Comment: Have you found any way to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Apparently you need to go into chrome on your mobile device, and it will pop up immediately.

Answer (score 0):

From the screen you have Select others on the left > then select the inspect > after that select the menu icon in the dev tools area(3 boxes ) > Select more tools > Select remote devices

Or Select the Menu button in chrome > more tools > Developer tools > Select the menu icon with in the dev tools sub window(3 boxes ) > Select more tools > Select Remote devices

You can also select the open devtools for current node > Select the menu icon with in the dev tools sub window(3 boxes ) > Select more tools > Select Remote devices

This should allow you to inspect on your connected android device

Comment: this requires the device to be found which is the question, so this does not work