# Android device recognized by adb but not recognized by Chrome development tools

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, adb, chrome-remote-debugging

I have an **Android** device recognized by `adb` devices but not recognized by **chrome** development tools (with or without discover **USB devices** checked).

My machine development is a **Mac** and I have

1. installed **Android Studio 3.1**
2. Installed **SDK** platforms **Android 8.0** and **8.1**
3. Installed **SDK Tools**: Android SDK **Build-Tools 28 rc-2**, Android **emulator**, Android SDK **platform-tools**, Android **SDK tools**, **Intel x86 emulator**, Android support **Repository** and **Google repository**

If disconnect and reconnect the cable, or if I switch **on/off** the **USB debugging** on my device makes no difference.

`ADB` **kill-server / start-server** don't produce any reaction in Chrome.

Apparently `adb` is working properly
I've already changed android development environment, from **android studio** to **brew cask version** (android-sdk, android-ndk, android-platform-tools) and vice-versa with no success (similar results).

I have reinstalled Chrome
Currently I have **android studio** and in my `~/bash_profile` I have set:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk
#export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk
#export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_$
export ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT=5038
```

This problem started a coupled of days ago. Previously worked fine for months. Not sure what led to the problem, but I made some trials with ionic dev app (not sure on any cause-effect) and some time after my development environment started with problems.
My problem is I cannot have remote debug with Chrome. I can deploy my ionic application into my connected mobile and run it, but not debug the development
Debugging with emulator is not efficient in my case since I use physical components such as scanning and photos
Any help help is more than welcome. I've spent hours with this ...

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925992/chrome-devtools-devices-does-not-detect-device-when-plugged-in

Comment: Please verify chrome is on latest version.

Comment: Problem still unsolved. Related suggestions are not my case nor provide the solution.

Comment: However made some more investigation. When I do adb kill-server (and kill pending processes using command lsof -i | grep 5037 and kill xxx, and also revoking USB authorisations) my device is viisble in Chrome. After adb start-server, I can still see it in Chrome. The moment my device is recognized by adb devices (through reconnect via USB debugging), it desappears from Chrome. I have device in adb or in Chrome, not in both as I used to have in the past. Any suggestions?