# Chrome: Remote Device cannot see Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017)

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, adb

I am using Windows 10. Desktop Chrome version: 71.0.3578.98. Android Chrome version: 71.0.3578.99.

On my **Samsung Galaxy A5** I have enabled Developer options.

- I have followed the official instructions from here:
  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/.
- I have also tried the really long related question here on
  stackoverflow:
  [Chrome DevTools Devices does not detect device when plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925992/chrome-devtools-devices-does-not-detect-device-when-plugged-in)
- I have downloaded and installed Samsung USB drivers (I have tried
  with and without these drivers)
- I have downloaded the Minimal ADB and Fastboot package
- I am able to launch ADB and when I plug my Galaxy A5 into the
  computer I can see it listed in ADB devices
- I also was able to add the RSA authorization for this PC
- I have tried changing the USB mode from MTP, PTP, Audio, and Charging
- I also tried a **Samsung Galaxy S8** which also did **not** work

Despite all this, I am seeing no devices in Chrome: Developer tools > More tools > Remote devices

This is really frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.