# Chrome Dev Tools Unable to Detect Device

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have set up Developer Mode on my Samsung Galaxy Note 9 and plug it into my Notebook and when I open `chrome://inspect/#devices`, it doesn't show any devices connected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the instructions from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22028058/196969) to [Chrome DevTools Devices does not detect device when plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925992/chrome-devtools-devices-does-not-detect-device-when-plugged-in)
starting from the line:

> **"Update 24 February 2016"**

I also have a Samsung phone and had the same problem.
This instruction works (I checked it up right now).